# onConfigurationChange does not get called

Tags: android, configuration

I am trying to handle the case where i need to refresh my view after an inapp language change has occurred

However, the method onConfigurationChange does not get called at all.

i put in my manifest the following flags:

```
 android:configChanges="locale"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"




public void onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration newConfig) {
        LogUtils.d("configuration has changed:%s",newConfig); => this line never runs
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    };
```

what do i do to make the onConfigurationChanged method run ?

Answer (score 0):

Android has an Intent registered to this task, ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED. So I believe you will have to have a BroadcastReceiver registered to listen this Intent filter and then do the necessary steps when you listen it. I am not sure about the entire code but here is a link which might help. http://android.codota.com/scenarios/518914fada0a610ad0c274da/android.content.IntentFilter?tag=out_2013_05_05_07_19_34